# Android layout problem

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i make a layout in XML with four button on the same line. I need the first and last button to be of specific width (40px) and the middle two to be of their content width (wrap_content)?

Sample how I would like to position buttons...

|-b1-|....|--b2--||---b3---|....|-b4-|

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, long time ago. A assume you've read the docs, but I'm pretty sure something similar is covered there.

Comment: I have tried reading the SDK docs, but i cannot find what i need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the four buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout. Define b1 with a layout_width of 40px, b2 and b3 with a layout_width of wrap_content, then b4 with a layout_width of 40px. If you want it centered, just set the LinearLayout's layout_width to fill_parent and give it a gravity of center_horizontal. Something like:

EDIT: Oh, if you're wanting the two 40px buttons on the sides, and the two wrap_content buttons centered, you could go two ways. Simplest method would be to add some blank Views to your LinearLayout (I'll demonstrate below), while a more lengthy way would be to use a RelativeLayout and put the two center buttons within a LinearLayout within that RelativeLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 4"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```